# Proving that the codomain of a surjective continuous fn, is connected if the domain is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Here is the question:

Show that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective continuous function, and if $X$ is connected, then $Y$ is also connected.

Where we have the following:

we say a space $X$ is connected if the only separations that $X$ has are trivial separations.

A separation of a space $X$ is a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Z,$ where $Z$ is the discrete two-point space. we say that a separation $f: X \rightarrow Z,$ of the space $X$ is a trivial separation if it is a constant function.

Still I do not know how to prove the question, could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $Y$ is not connected, i.e. there exists a continuous surjection $g\colon Y\to Z$. Is $g\circ f\colon X\to Z$ a trivial separation?

Comment: No, because the composition of 2 surjective functions is a surjective function and hence not constant and hence not the trivial separation which contradicts that $X$ is connected. am I correct?

Comment: Exactly! (Implicitly we're using the trivial fact that composition of two continuous functions is continuous).